# cmd does not show actual ip adress

Tags: raspbian, boot, static-ip

I have a problem in determining the IP address for my Raspberry Pi 2.

Before RPi's IP address was 192.X.X.X, but after I rebooted the system, the IP address became 202.X.X.X. i dont setup any static address on it.

i am connect the raspberrypi to monitor laptop using putty and ssh connection.

I don't know why this happened.

When I connect my windows to Raspberry Pi, after doing the ping its show address 202.X.X.X.
I have tried using the IP address 202.X.X.x but still cannot connect to Raspberry Pi.

ping i use to get raspi address was ping raspberrypi.mshome.net on cmd

Hope to get some solution from others.

Comment: Did you setup static ip ?

Comment: no... i dont setup anything...

Comment: Can you get post output of `ifconfig` ?

Comment: i cannot connect my raspi to laptop screen.. so i cannot put any input command to raspberry

Comment: How can you be sure that IP address changed and in range 202.x.x.x ?

Comment: i use cmd in windows 7 to check ip address... i type ping raspberypi.mshome,net to know my raspi address

Comment: I think you need to rewrite your question and explain **clearly** the problem, how your Pi is wired, what you have tried so far **step by step**, ...